# Mybatis: get name of the column from mapped bean property

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

Is there any way I can retrieve the column name from a bean property?

For example I have a user table

```
user(user_id,user_name)
```

and a class

```
class User{
private Integer userId;
private String userName;
//getter setter
}
```

I have a resultMap in my configuration file

```
 <resultMap id="userMap" type="User">
    <id property="userId" column="user_id" javaType="Integer" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
    <result property="userName" column="user_name" javaType="String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" /> 
 </resultMap>
```

Is there any way i can get the String  **user_id** if i have the string **userId**

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need it?

Comment: i need it to generate a sql dynamically

Comment: I wondered about the same, but from what I have seen so far, you have to write it all manually. Not sure though. Make the idea more general and request a feature, I'll support it. http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/entry

Answer (score 1):

Does the following code snippet satisfy your requirements?

```
String propertyName = "userId";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9])([A-Z])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(propertyName);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1) + "_" + m.group(2).toLowerCase());
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Configuration configuration = sessionFactory.getConfiguration();
    ResultMap resultMap = configuration.getResultMap("User");
    for(ResultMapping resultMapping : resultMap.getResultMappings()) {
        System.out.println(resultMapping.getColumn() + "::"+resultMapping.getProperty());
    }
```

get column-property mapping one by one, and then can get the column name of your property.